# oneliner using pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How would I implment this code using pandas or numpy?

```
x =[]
for i in xrange(1,6):
    x.append(i)
print x
combi = (list(itertools.permutations(x, 5)))

for i  in combi:
    print i
    l = (i[0]) + abs(i[0] - i[1]) + abs(i[1] - i[2]) + abs(i[2] - i[3]) + abs(i[3] - i[4])
    print l
```

output of combi is

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)
(1, 2, 4, 3, 5)
(1, 2, 4, 5, 3)
```

I try to add the first number in each tuple to difference of second third 4th and fifth for each tuple which give me this

```
5
6
7
7
```

easier if increase my range to 10 i will have to write the code for variable l upto 10.

Comment: *memory wise*, you can optimise by avoiding using these 2 lists, start with `combi = itertools.permutations(xrange(1,6), 5)`. if you iterate over an iterator from itertools then you don't need the list call

Comment: ok, how do i optimize thi susing lamba, pandas or numpy if my n= 10 or 100

Comment: At this point, it seems that your question isn't about optimization, lambda functions, pandas or numpy at all. You want to know how to use an arbitrary number `n` instead of 5.

Comment: Optimize for what? And why do you want to use lambdas, pandas or numpy?

Comment: optimize this block `l = (i[0]) + abs(i[0] - i[1]) + abs(i[1] - i[2]) + abs(i[2] - i[3]) + abs(i[3] - i[4])`  if i increase the range to 10 i will have to manually type this till 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the `diff` between subsequent elements, and then summing the `abs` of those diffs and then you add to that, the first element in the sequence:

**Code:**

```
for i in it.permutations(xrange(1, 6), 5):
    k = i[0] + sum(np.abs(np.diff(i)))
```

**Test Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

for i in it.permutations(xrange(1, 6), 5):
    k = i[0] + sum(np.abs(np.diff(i)))
    l = (i[0]) + abs(i[0] - i[1]) + abs(i[1] - i[2]) + abs(i[2] - i[3]) + abs(i[3] - i[4])
    assert l == k
```